# Sorting DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have set the Columns of the DataGridView to 
SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
But on the click on the cell header, it does not sort it

Deos anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Do you have a `SortExpression` on the column?

Comment: i have just written for every column that column.sortmode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
I dont knw anything about SortExpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method Sort in datagridview

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["yourcol"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource has to be sortable

a DataTable/DataView is sortable

a List is not sortable (by properties) for itself

Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic